# MockMvc does not handle AccessDeniedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc

I have a post call that runs something like this

```
 assertThrows("Access Denied for non Blappity Roles",
                 () -> mvc.perform(post(url)
                                    .content(requestStr)
                                    .accept(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                                    .with(csrf())
                                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                               .andExpect(__ -> assertThat(__.getResolvedException(),                                             CoreMatchers.instanceOf(AccessDeniedException.class))),
                 Matchers.instanceOf(AccessDeniedException.class))
```

I do have an Exception Handler defined this way

```
   @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
 public void accessDeniedException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Exception e) throws Exception {
     e.printStackTrace(System.err);
     log.error("Access Denied Exception {}", e.getClass(), e);
     throw e;
```

No matter what, the test fails, and mockmvc perform does not capture the AccessDeniedException, and the test fails with.. guess what, AccessDeniedException that escapes my Matcher.
What I am guessing is, the exception I am throwing is being gobbled by another filter somewhere. Is there anyway I can get MockMvc to get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you re-throw `AccessDeniedException` from its `@ExceptionHandler` ,it is considered as unresolved exception but `MockMvc` will only capture the resolved exception. So `AccessDeniedException` is never resolved and hence `getResolvedException()` is null.

Normally you do not need to rethrow the exception from `@ExceptionHandler` , just handle it by configuring what HTTP status code or response body should be replied in the HTTP response.

Also suppose you really resolve `AccessDeniedException` , you do not need to wrap the `mockMvc.perform()` in the `assertThrows()`. Just use `mockMvc.perform().andExpect(xxx)` for assertion.

Comment: Sheesh, I wanted that Matcher assertion, was fixated on that. That's it, I removed the assertThrows and it works just fine. Thank you Ken